# Huge time difference when making a set inside a list comprehension compared to outside

Tags: python

I have the test case below, where I find the elements present in two strings and return them in the order of the first string. Why is the second case, where `set(string2)` is done inside the list comprehension over an order of magnitude slower?

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit(
    """
    import random, string
    string1 = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(100000))
    string2 = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(100000))
    v=set(string2)
    [x for x in string1 if x in v]
    """,
    number=10,
)
# 2.005337953567505

timeit.timeit(
    """
    import random, string
    string1 = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(100000))
    string2 = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(100000))
    [x for x in string1 if x in set(string2)]
    """,
    number=10,
)
# 22.1062970161438
```

Comment: It is only efficient if you use an already created set in your comprehension, created with `{}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is building the `set(string2)` set for every iteration of the 'loop' in the list comprehension. It doesn't 'know' that it's the same set every time.

E.g. Every time python executes the list comprehension `if` clause, `x in set(string2)` is evaluated, which means the set is created every time. Since x is each char of a 100000 character string, this means the (same) set is being built 100000 times in the second case, but only once in the first case (where you define the set as `v`).